# Nunit System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

This is method i want to test:

```
void Update(User user)
{
    if (_userQuery.IsNameExist(user.Guid, (int) user.UserId, user.Name))
        UpdateUser(user);
}
```

Below test class with method `Update_Test()` which should test above one.

```
[TestFixture]
class ModifyuserServiceTest
{
    private IModifyUserService ModifyUserService { get; set; }
    private Mock<IUserQuery> UserQuery { get; set; }
    private Mock<IUserRepository> UserRepository { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        userQuery = new Mock<IUserQuery>();
        UserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        ModifyUserService = new ModifyUserService(userQuery.Object, UserRepository.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Update_Test()
    {
        userQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsNameExist(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(true);

        ModifyuserService.Update(new User());

        UserRepository.Verify(uow => uow.Add(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

For whatever reason i get error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value.
```

When i debug test method it raises error on this line in tested method:

```
if (_userQuery.IsNameExist(user.Guid, (int) user.UserId, user.Name))
```

When i look into arguments values there are: `0, null, null` which seems to be funny as in my test method i specified in `userQuery.Setup` :

```
It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()
```

I even tried like this:

```
userQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsNameExist(999, 33, "whatever"))
```

nevertheless again same error occurs and values there shows : `0, null, null`

What is wrong here?

**Update:**

```
public bool IsNameExist(int guid, int userId, string name)
{
     Parameters = new List<IDbDataParameter>
     {
        Context.CreateParameter("@Guid", guid, DbType.Int64),
        Context.CreateParameter("@userId", userId, DbType.Int64),
        Context.CreateParameter("@Name", name, DbType.String)
     };

    var count = (int)Context.GetScalarValue($"SELECT count(*) FROM {UserTable} WHERE userId=@userId And Guid=@Guid And Name=@Name", CommandType.Text,
                 Parameters.ToArray(), null);

      return count > 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `IsNameExist`

Comment: @Nkosi i posted but i do not think it's directly because of that method.

Comment: Include `UpdateUser` as it is part of the method under test

Comment: @Nkosi i do not know - i even mark it virtual right now but it doesn't change situation

Comment: @Nkosi Update is not even reached at that point

Comment: Need to see the members involved. Show `IUserQuery` and `User` so we can narrow down what is being used.

Comment: Some one of the members shown is a nullable, but since we do not know the full context of the code being used, we can only guess

Comment: My guess would be the `user.UserId`

Comment: User's UserId property is int? but should doesn't matter as i put value into IsNameExist ..It looks like Setup doesn;t setup anything and when it comes to: ModifyuserService.Update(new User()); it goes inside and put default User's property values instead of the one from Setup

Comment: I just ran a test `int? x = null; int y = (int)x;` and it fails with the same error message. This has nothing to do with the moq setup. you are trying to cast a null to int. So that means that the user id passed to the method under test is null. You need to set a value for the user id.

Comment: @Nkosi but isn't Setup put values i put in Setup? I do not understand P.S It's hard for me to extract more as i already extracted simplifying things i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a test

```
int? x = null; 
int y = (int)x; //System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'
```

and it fails with the same error message in your test

This has nothing to do with the MOQ Setup.

Your method under test is trying to cast `null` to `int`, causing a run-time error.

That implies that the `UserId` passed to the method under test is null.

You need to set a value for the user id so the test can be exercised to completion.

```
//...

var user = new User() {
    UserId = 0
};

ModifyuserService.Update(user);

//...
```

Comment: you right if i put: ModifyuserService.Update(new User() {UserId = 10); then test going well. But i dont understand. .. As long as i specify behaviour and values for IsNameExist in Setup of it. This method should take values i specified there. So if i do: userQuery.Setup(uow => uow.IsNameExist(11, 20,"whatever"))
                .Returns(true); those values should be taken ?

Comment: @Arie No. The setup just tells the mock what to expect. It does not actually pass values when executing.

Comment: @Arie you specify what values the mock "expects" to receive so that it will behave as expected when invoked. If you don't care what values is passed, that is what `It.IsAny` is for.

Comment: @Nkoise and that's what i did (i put initialy IsAny ..). Nevertheless what could be even the reason to put something else than IsAny like real value to the Setup - if as you said values are not used? I do not get it.

Comment: could you also tell me about this virtual methods? My methods are not virtual nevertheless after your hint it still working without marking them virtual. Cany you explain?

Comment: @Arie I removed that comment once I realized you were mocking the interface and not the class.

Comment: can you answer on the prev comment please?

Comment: @Arie The overall gist is that the problem was not with the mock. Your code was failing before the mock was invoked. thec code tries to cast the null before the mocked member was invoked.

Comment: the question was, what is the sense to set values in Setup method since those values are not used? Like in my example i set some values in Setup of IsNameExist nevertheless at the end in Update method those values was past by this call : ModifyuserService.Update(new User() . I dont understand this